# ¿Por que me aparece error en el if(condicion)||(condicion){}?

Tags: java

Calcular el número de pulsaciones que debe tener una persona por cada 10 segundos de ejercicio aeróbico; la formula que se aplica cuando el sexo es femenino es: num_pulsaciones = (220 − edad)/10 y si el sexo es masculino: num_pulsaciones = (210 − edad)/10.
¿y como pudo validar la informacion del condicional?

```
  int edad,sexo,np ;
  Scanner a=new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.println("INGRESE LA EDAD");
  edad=a.nextInt();
  System.out.println("INGRESE 1 SI ES DE SEXO FEMENINO O 2 SI ES DE SEXO MASCULINO");`introducir el código aquí`
  sexo=a.nextInt();

  if(sexo==1)||(2==sexo){}

  if (sexo==1){
    np=(220-edad)/10;
  }
   else
   np=(210-edad)/10;
   System.out.println("EL NUMERO DE PULSACIONES SON: "  +np );
   }
    
    }   
    
    
    
    }
```

Comment: Las 2 condiciones a evaluar deben ir dentro de la pareja de paréntesis  principal así: `if(sexo==1 || sexo == 2){}` además del lado izquierdo debe ir el valor que vas a comparar las 2 ocasiones que sería `sexo`

Comment: el if esta solo afectando al primero `if(sexo==1)`, lo demás será error, has lo que te indica @BetaM, y se solucionara.

Comment: Dale una repasada a la estructura de los condicionales, [aquí información útil y oficial al respecto](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

Comment: gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Adicional a lo que responde @BetaM puedes consultar también la condicional **?** lo vas a encontrar útil en la programación.

Cuando tienes un simple if como

```
if (sexo == 1)
   masculino = x;
else
   Femenino = y;
```

Puedes utilizar el condicional ternario:
**resultado = (Tu_condicion) ? valor1 : valor2;**

más información en esta [fuente](http://lineadecodigo.com/java/el-operador-ternario-en-java/)

Rehice tu código y quedo asi:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  int edad,sexo, numeroPulsaciones ;
  Scanner age=new Scanner (System.in);
  Scanner sex=new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.println("INGRESE LA EDAD");
  edad=age.nextInt();
    
  System.out.println("INGRESE 1 SI ES DE SEXO FEMENINO O 2 SI ES DE SEXO MASCULINO");
  sexo=sex.nextInt();
  numeroPulsaciones = (sexo==2) ? (220-edad)/10 : (210-edad)/10;
  System.out.println("EL NUMERO DE PULSACIONES SON: "  + numeroPulsaciones );
   
  }
 }
```

puedes ver el código corriendo [aquí](https://repl.it/join/qevddlnt-gregdorian)

Falta Aclarar que te faltan validaciones y demás ( como que los números para sexo sean solo 1 y 2, y la edad que no sea 0 y estén entre 1 y 100, considerando que una persona pueda vivir hasta 100 o un poco más)

Comment: Conviene le aclares que ese `?` es un operador ternario y que agregaras como funciona su estructura pues el OP estaba un poco perdido con el if convencional, si le proponemos algo mas es bueno o necesario explicarlo

Comment: BetaM creo que sí, tienes razón mejoraré la respuesta.

Comment: ¿y como pudo validar la  informacion del condicional?